# Add Delete Method in a RESTful web service

Tags: java, mysql, rest

I am making my first RESTful web service (using MySQL). But I don't know how to remove records from a table by id.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Search for a person by id and return the result(id, full name and age) in XML format:

   ```
   private PersonDao personDao = new PersonDao();
   //method which return a single person in xml
   @GET
   @Path("/getPersonByIdXML/{id}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public Person getPersonByIdXML(@PathParam("id")int id){
       return personDao.getPersonById(id);
   }

   // return JSON response
   ```
2. Search for a person by id and return the result(id, full name and age) in JSON format:

   ```
   @GET
   @Path("/getPersonByIdJSON/{id}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Person getPersonById(@PathParam("id")int id){
       return personDao.getPersonById(id);
   }
   ```
3. Output all persons and return the result(id, full name and age) in JSON format:

   ```
   // the method returns list of all persons
   @GET
   @Path("/getAllPersonsInXML")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<Person> getAllPersonsInXML(){
       return personDao.getAllPersons();
   }
   ```
4. Insert a person in the database:

   ```
   //insert
   @GET
   @Path("/insertPerson/{fullName}/{age}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String saveNewPerson(@PathParam("fullName") String fullName, @PathParam("age") int age) {
       Person person = new Person();

       person.setFullName(fullName);
       person.setAge(age);

       if (!personDao.savePerson(person)) {
           return "{\"status\":\"ok\"}  id="+person.getId();
       }
       else {
           return "{\"status\":\"not ok\"}";
       }
   }
   ```
5. Edit a person in the database:

   ```
   //update
   @GET
   @Path("/insertPerson/{id}/{fullName}/{age}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String updatePerson(@PathParam("id") int id, @PathParam("fullName") String fullName, @PathParam("age") int age) {
       Person person = new Person();
       person.setId(id);
       person.setFullName(fullName);
       person.setAge(age);

       if (!personDao.savePerson(person)) {
           return "{\"status\":\"ok\"}";
       }
       else {
           return "{\"status\":\"not ok\"}";
       }    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a DELETE resource:

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{id}")
public void deleteById(@PathParam("id")int id){
   personDao.deleteById(id);
}
```

As long as you have the deleteById method constructed then Thanks it!

Suggestions:

- Your insert is a GET. Should really be a POST since you are creating something.
- Your update is a GET. Should really be a PUT.
  Have fun and keep at it!!

Comment: thanks, i am make deleteById method, but he not work. Code below in the next answer

Answer (score 0):

this method for getPersonById:

```
    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
    Person person = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        person = (Person) session.createQuery("from Person p where p.id = :ID").setParameter("ID", id).uniqueResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return person;
}
```

this method for Delete:

```
    public void deleteById(int id) {
    Person person = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        person = (Person) session.createQuery("delete Person p where p.id = :ID");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

deleteById not work, output error 204 No Content, how do correct method for deleteById, thanks

Comment: 204 is not an error it just means there was no content returned. That's expected in this case because the DELETE is a void. Check your DB to see if the record has been removed. Logic looks ok to me, but I haven't done my mysql java work in a little while.